# Separating power depending on voltage

Tags: voltage, switches, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, switching-regulator

I just started working on a computer science project that requires me to do some hardware stuff, but I am a complete noob most of it. For a part of the project I need to be able to forward a current stream depending on its voltage. Something like in the picture.[image: ![enter image description here]

I was wondering if there is an electrical component that can do it.
Thanks in advance and sorry if the question violates any of the stackexchange's rules!

Comment: Do you mean IN=6V --> OUT1=6V, OUT2=0V and IN=4V --> OUT1=0V, OUT2=4V? I'm thinking a comparator that drives a multiplexer or two P-MOS or two relays could do this (depending on the range of current). But I think this is an odd thing to do and I wonder if you're trying to solve the right question.

Comment: There exists Boost and Buck voltage converters, but buy what you need for Voltage and power or just use a PC PSU. But if this is a learning how to switch voltages, you need to define it better

Comment: @AndersPetersson That's exactly what I meant. The thing I am trying to do is separate high and normal voltage from USB data pins in order to prevent power surges by USB killers. I want the port to operate normally if the current is less or 5V and switch to ground if it is more, so it won't destroy the electronics after the port.

Comment: @IvanZlatanov It would probably be easier to try to short out or clamp the voltage spike than to redirect it.

Comment: (btw, if you could redirect it, why would you need to redirect it somewhere? you could just leave the "more than 5V" output connected to *nothing* and the voltage still wouldn't go to the computer)

Comment: @user253751 How can I do it?

Comment: @user253751 That is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such component. Perhaps you could build a circuit that does this, but I don't think you need one.

You could look at [TVS diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode), which will conduct current when the voltage is above a certain amount. By connecting one between each data wire and the ground wire, if the voltage goes too high, current will flow to ground which causes the voltage to decrease. Whether it will work well enough to protect the computer, I can't say.

The energy in the voltage pulse will be absorbed by the diode, so (depending on what sort of quality you need for your project) you should also work out whether there is a risk of overheating. If there is a risk of overheating, then you could include some circuit to turn off the USB power for a while after a voltage spike is detected, so the USB killer can't keep sending pulses.

Answer (score 0):

Protecting against USB killers is in principle not different from protecting from inadvertent ESD events. Automotive electronics is an example of an application which emphasises electric protection -- if you search for this topic you will quickly find solutions. As user253751 writes, TVS diodes is a common form of protection that is also easy to implement. Resettable fuses might also be helpful.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Killer), USB killers can reach 220 V on the data lines. This is not an unusual number for a natural ESD event. What could be different is the duration and current-delivery capability of a USB killer, which I imagine can overheat any component not dimensioned for this specific scenario.

Though it's good practice to protect against electrical risks (and to some degree required for certification of electrical products), I wouldn't worry too much about malicious attacks simply because they are in general rare. Also, it's very hard to protect against ingenuity; what if someone simply pours glue into the USB port?

Comment: The asker did say it's "a computer science project" so usefulness is not necessarily a factor. Also you can often do more damage with a USB killer than by pouring glue into the port, because it can damage important parts of the computer. (okay, you could pour glue over the *entire computer* to have the same effect...)

Comment: Ok I agree that usefulness might not be the goal. My point wasn't specifically about glue, but that it's easy to overlook how devastating even a low-tech attack can be.